# using miles rather than kilometers in solr spatial searches

Tags: solr, geolocation

When using solr's spatial search feature, how can I tell it to use miles rather than km when calculating values.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [javadoc of the class that implements `geofilt`](https://builds.apache.org/job/Solr-trunk/javadoc/org/apache/solr/search/SpatialFilterQParserPlugin.html) says "All units are in Kilometers"

It was decided that [configurable units would only complicate things](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1568?focusedCommentId=12884028&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-12884028).

Which means that it's up to you to do the conversions (it's trivial code really).

Comment: Mauricio is correct. Just convert your value (in miles) to KM before passing to SOLR.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 5.0 (released february 2015) and onwards, miles can be used as well. Also degrees can be used as units.

In the schema.xml file you would configure the `<fieldType>` tag as follows:

`<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType/" distanceUnits="miles" />`

Please note that as of version 6.0, `distanceUnits` is used instead of `units`, which is deprecated.

See the [user guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html#SpatialSearch-Schemaconfiguration) for further configurations.